# Jquery Mobile first time the app opens it keep loading

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an app for android platoform using PhoneGap and JqueryMobile.
The problem is whenever I install the app it will open but it keep loading if I exit the app and open it again it will work probably. It only happens the first time after that its fine.
I've being struggling to solve this issue but I couldn't find any solutions.
P.S its an offline app.
Your help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i figured it out. Which is you can't put anything under `super.loadUrl("");`